# Can you clone a linux external hard drive to another external hard drive?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have a Linux Mint hard drive, from a dead computer, in an enclosure that I want to clone to another external hard drive.

Comment: Yes you can. There are lots of good questions here about cloning drives. Have you looked at those?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the computer isn't dead because of the drive, `dd` will do what you need.

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb

if = source disk
of = target disk
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to simply recover your home directory or would you like to copy the entire drive to another drive? Assuming that the drive in the enclosure isn't damaged I believe you could simply transfer it into a new enclosure. but otherwise you would need a way to connect both drives to a machine and copy the contents from one drive to the other. I'm not 100% but I believe dd can get the job done, but don't quote me on that.